# Use JS/Jquery to move div's in ASP form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Full disclosure, I asked about this a few days ago but am still working on it and have not found a solution. I will provide as much information as possible and hopefully get some traction.

- I have a div element with ID #formContainer. It contains an ASP form
- The form contains a Timer control which fires every 10 seconds
- The form contains several very similar div elements, which all contain a DetailsView control for viewing SqlDataSource data
- Each of these similar div elements has an UpdatePanel
- Each UpdatePanel uses the Timer control of the form, so that SQL data is updated in each DetailsView every 10 seconds

Here is where the behavior of the page comes into play...

When each DetailsView is updated:

- If the text value of a specific column in the DetailsView == X, the div is **shown** on the page
- If the text value of that same column == Y, the div is **hidden** (jQuery)

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-10" id="formContainer">

<form id ="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnablePageMethods="true" />

    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer1_Click" Enabled="True" />

    <div class="square" id="myDiv1">
        <div class="profileContainer">
            <div class="profilePicContainer">
                <div class="myPic1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="profileContent">
                <div class="table">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn1" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btn1_Click" />
                            <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="Grid" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataKeyNames="PhysicalAddress">                                    
                                <Fields>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OwnerName" HeaderText="OwnerName" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="OwnerName" >
                                        <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Building" HeaderText="Building" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="OwnerName" ItemStyle-CssClass="altText" >
                                        <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeOn" HeaderText="TimeOn" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="OwnerName" >
                                        <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="IPAddress" HeaderText="IPAddress" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="OwnerName" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide" >
                                        <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                </Fields>
                                <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />                                    
                            </asp:DetailsView>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="square" id="myDiv2">
        <div class="profileContainer">
            <div class="profilePicContainer">
                <div class="myPic2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="profileContent">
                <div class="table">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn2" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btn2_Click" />                                  
                            <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" CssClass="Grid" DataKeyNames="PhysicalAddress">
                                <Fields>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OwnerName" HeaderText="OwnerName" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="OwnerName">
                                        <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Building" HeaderText="Building" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="Building" ItemStyle-CssClass="altText">
                                        <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeOn" HeaderText="TimeOn" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="TimeOn">
                                        <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="IPAddress" HeaderText="IPAddress" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="IPAddress" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide">
                                        <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                </Fields>
                                <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:DetailsView>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Timer1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
        DetailsView1.DataBind();
        UpdatePanel2.Update();
        DetailsView2.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["OwnerName"].DefaultValue = "Owner1";
        SqlDataSource1.Update();
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
        DetailsView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["OwnerName"].DefaultValue = "Owner2";
        SqlDataSource2.Update();
        UpdatePanel2.Update();
        DetailsView2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Here is how I am *hiding or showing each div element with the .square class* when the UpdatePanels are updated...

**JS**

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function () {

    $('.square').each(function () {

        //convert each element with class .square to a string
        var square = $(this).html().toString();

        //if square is at locationA OR has no IP, hide it
        if ((square.indexOf("locationA") != -1) || (square.indexOf("10.") === -1)) {

            $(this).hide();

        }

        //else if square is NOT at locationA OR HAS an IP, show it
        else if ((square.indexOf("locationA") === -1) || (square.indexOf("10.") != -1)) {

            $(this).show();                

        }


    })
})
```

So, all of this works, but I would like to have each .square div elements ordered on the page alphabetically by the text value of .square (tr:eq(1).find('td').text(). The sort works, but it replaces the page elements and everything stops working. The UpdatePanels no longer updated, other jQuery click events stop working...

**SORT**

```
    $('.square').sort(function (a, b) {

    if ($(a).find('tr:eq(1)').find('td').text() < $(b).find('tr:eq(1)').find('td').text()) {

        return -1;

    }

    else {

        return 1;

    }
}).appendTo('#formContainer');
```

})

Please advise on any method for sorting these divs and not replacing them so that all other functionality will still work.

Thank you!!

Comment: I would suggest do the ordering at server level as both the DetailsView holding the same data so sort them server level only and then assign the first one to first and second to second it will be less headache

Comment: Thank you Zaki. Can you elaborate on this? Where is HTML sorting done at the server level?